# QGIS update to 3.14 Pi

Tags: qgis-3, windows, update

I try to update QGIS to 3.14 version with osgeo4w-setup-x86_64 but 3.14 does not appear in list. It only shows 3.12

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I solved it when I changed the download site to ftp.osuosl.org.

It looked funny to me because after trying this one I decided to try the previous two again (osgeo4w-oslandia and OSGeo), that I unsuccessfully tested before osuosl... And it worked! QGIS 3.14 Pi was there in the Desktop installation options, contrarily to my first test.

I don't know if you will have the same options as I do, but I would try to change sources until one of them works. If not, then come back here and tell us what happened.

[image: Try to change the source...]

Comment: it works for me changing source like you.  thank you very much :D

Comment: Please accept his answer (click the checkmark) to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using osgeo4w-setup-x86_64 try advanced install, from the web,  it will show this in the desktop section:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. I have Q installed on three different machines which I use regularly. 3.14.0-1 only shows up in the advanced install screen on one of them. The other two machines seem stuck at the previous version, as the OP seems to be experiencing as well.

Comment: That is kind of weird, OSGeo4W is a nework installer, that is why I mention to choose advanced install instead of express desktop or express Web options. I have 3.14 on two different machines. Also I am asuming you are using windows...is that the case?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing as JoshC, @Gerardo. I'm on Windows 10, and even under the advanced install 3.12 is the only version that shows up. Doesn't matter if I select current or experimental. Same situation on two different computers.

Comment: It is the case, yes. Changing the installation source URL didn't seem to change anything, either.